# How can I make JBehave work nicely with expectation-driven APIs?

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

The conventional way to write a BDD scenario is:

```
 Given [some preconditions]
 When [My code runs]
 Then [some stuff happened]
```

But I am working with a mock-like API that wants expectations (that is, "some stuff happened") defined before the code under test is run. To be in sympathy with that API, I have to write my story like this:

```
Given [some preconditions]
And [the expectation that some stuff is going to happen]
When [My code runs]
Then [the expectations I defined above were met]
```

I don't want to do that. I can see two kludgy ways around it, which I also don't really want to do:

- Implicitly set up "any" type expectations in some of the "Given" steps, use the "capture" feature of the mocking API to stash calls into fields, and check those in the "Then" steps.
- ... or make the "When" step set a field telling an AfterScenario step to run my code, hence deferring it to after the expectations have been set (but preventing me from checking other postconditions)

What I'd really like is for JBehave to look at the Then steps, find the parts of them that are setting expectations, and run those before the When.

Spock achieves this with its mocks (comments show execution order):

```
def translator = Mock(Translator)

void "test something" {
    given: 
      testObj = new MyThing(translator)  // 1
    when:
      def actual = testObj.run("foo")   // 3
    then:
      1 * translator.process("foo") << "bar" // 2 (setup) 
                                             // and 4 (post-check)
      actual == "bar"  // 5
}
```

Is there a neat pattern to make JBehave do this?

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, JBehave 1.0, the first BDD tool, used to have its own mocking framework, and used to behave in the same way as Spock. It was nasty. Really, really nasty (from a BDD perspective; from a "strict mock" testing perspective it was fine).

The pattern was the only way any mocking framework worked at the time, and led to the invention of Mockito and the other "nice" mocking frameworks (and the removal of aforementioned mocking framework from JBehave 2.0 as it was no longer needed).

So, the "neat pattern" is to write your own mocking framework, if Mockito doesn't do the job for you. The not-so-neat pattern is to write your own BDD framework. Having a mocking framework that matches reality is generally simpler IMO.

Alternatively, you may find that the mocking framework you're using has a "nice" mode or allows you to declare stubs rather than mocks, which might help. Without knowing which framework you're using it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. The "mock-like" framework I'm using is actually a mock REST service; rest-client-driver, in which you tell an embedded Jetty what HTTP requests to expect, so I can't switch to Mockito.

Comment: @slim There isn't a huge amount of code there. Bet you could fork it and write something that suits what you do in a couple of days.